# Can you mount motherboard spacers/standoffs into plastic?

Tags: motherboard, mount, case, case-mods

I'm planning on building a custom computer case out of acrylic plastic.
With little-to-none electrical engineering experience I'm wondering if the motherboard spacers needs to be screwed into a grounded piece of metal (as it is on a normal aluminium case, to its back-plate), or if it is sufficient to just mount them directly into the plastic?

Are there any other static/electricity issues i need to take into account when building this case?

Comment: This is by no means cannonical, but I've used non-conductive standoffs before (nylon/plastic) and got 7+ years out of that motherboard (it is a very nice ABit board) without difficulties. I would be distressed to find that the mobo grounded out through the case and not the powersupply, which should have less resistance to ground.

Comment: In most instances Frank is right. **BUT** the design of the motherboard is important to this decision. Read the instructions carefully for the requirements of your specific board.

Comment: They make electrostatic air cleaners out of plastic.    Moving air through/past them builds up a huge charge (I forget whether acrylic is one of the resins).  So there is that.  The case also provides shielding (in both directions), which you won't get with an unlined plastic case.